# What are the Klingon symbols for 11 and 12?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

I'm making a clock, and I've run into a stumbling block. There's guides all over the place for how to count in Klingon, but they only seem to go up to 10.

I know that 11 and 12 are wa'mah wa' and wa'mah cha' respectively, but I can't find any resource to actually show me how this 'mah construction would look in Klingon script (other than non-canon sources that just place a 1 and a 1 together to make 11).

**What are the Klingon symbols for the numbers 11 and 12?**

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8c/3f/de/8c3fdeeca8c9ca4ba6b8c49e5933a794.jpg

Comment: That's a direct replacement of characters, like making 10 out of "1" and "0". I'm really more in the market for some canon source on how it works. I mean, maybe that is how it works, but I'm trying to be as authentic as possible.

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to make it a little clearer what you're asking for and also that you want a fully canon source if possible,

Comment: @Heremod: "That's a direct replacement of characters, like making 10 out of '1' and '0'." - *if* Klingon uses 10 as a base and writes numbers in positional notation, an apparent "direct replacement of characters" wouldn't be an unexpected outcome (quite unlike if we were talking about words or other written parts of language).

Comment: I thought my answer was reasonably comprehensive, given the quote from Okrand's "The Klingon Dictionary". Is there anything else you think I should address before you consider an acceptance?

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Klingon Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Klingon_Dictionary) (written by Mark Okrand), Klingon numbers are formed in base ten in precisely the same way that they're portrayed in English. **Eleven is 1(ten) and 1, Twelve is 1(ten) and 2.**

> In accordance with the more accepted practice, the Klingon Empire sometime back adopted a decimal number system, one based on ten. Though no one knows for sure, it is likely that this change was made more out of concern for understanding the scientific data of other civilizations than out of a spirit of cooperation
>
> The Klingon numbers are:
>   1   {wa1}
>   2   {cha1}
>   3   {wej}
>   4   {loS}
>   5   {vagh}
>   6   {jav}
>   7   {Soch}
>   8   {chorgh}
>   9   {Hut}
>   10  {wa'maH}
>
> **Higher numbers are formed by adding special number-forming elements to the basic set of numbers (1—9).** Thus, {wa'maH}  consists of {wa'}  plus the number-forming element for  {maH.} Counting continues as follows:
>   **11**  {wa'maH wa1} (that is, <**ten and one**>)
>   **12**  {wa'maH cha'} (that is, <**ten and two**>) etc.

Using the [standard(pIqaD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets)  Klingon Alphabet;

[image]

11 would be

[image]

12 would be

[image]

The following (analogue) clock was created by [several members of the Klingon Language Institute](http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/ClockSoftware).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Klingon uses base 10, just like English does.  10 is just the symbol for 1 followed by the symbol for 0.  Their system is described here: http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/Numbers, and here: http://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-klingon/en/tlh/

This page has a digital clock using Klingon numerals:
http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/PIqaD